# using an array as a class property in php

Tags: php

I tried to create a class with the properties like so:

```
class foo{

private $dbFields['test']=array("mobilePhone","address");
private $dbFields['test2']=array("mobilePhone","address",'colour');

}
```

but its not valid.

**PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in**

I had to do this which has the same result; but is less friendly for me editing in the future

```
class foo{

private $dbFields=array('test'=>array("mobilePhone","address"),'test2'=>array("mobilePhone","address",'colour'));

}
```

is there anyway to achieve the original structure or something simular?

Comment: It's a terrible question actually, I suggest reading [How to ask a good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with the following [class properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php#example-180) syntax:

```
<?php
class foo {
    private $dbFields = array(
        'test' => array("mobilePhone","address"),
        'test2' => array("mobilePhone","address","colour")
    );
}
```

If the values are dynamic, and not as it looks (like a reference to database columns), then you should pass the values to the class constructor as suggested by B.Desai answer.

And if the values never change perhaps using a [class constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) would be nicer (PHP >=5.3.0).

```
<?php
class foo {
    const dbFields = array(
        'test'  => array("mobilePhone","address"),
        'test2' => array("mobilePhone","address","colour")
    );
}
```

Comment: this one is short and nice solution.+1

Comment: i guess just twiddling the code formatter is as good idea as any

Comment: +1 for array constants. Note that these require PHP 5.6 or later, which shouldn't be an issue these days.

Answer (score 3):

Always initialize class member in constructor. This way you can assign any dynamic value also to data member.

```
class foo{

private $dbFields;
function __construct()
{
  $this->dbFields['test']=array("mobilePhone","address");
  $this->dbFields['test2']=array("mobilePhone","address",'colour');
}
function getFields()
{
  return $this->dbFields;
}
}
$obj = new foo();
print_r($obj->getFields());
```